# set type in creating post using google plus domain API

Tags: php, google-plus-domains

With my code, i can create a post on my profile, but it always show on my profile "share with domain" although i want it's "public". Please help me, thank you so much.

here my code:

```
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($oauth_credentials);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write');
$client->setScopes('email');
$client->getAccessToken();
$client->verifyIdToken();

$plusdomains = new Google_Service_PlusDomains($client);

$activityObject = new Google_Service_PlusDomains_ActivityObject();
$activityObject->setContent("Somethings's not importance");
$activityAccess = new Google_Service_PlusDomains_Acl();
$activityAccess->setDomainRestricted(true);

$resource = new Google_Service_PlusDomains_PlusDomainsAclentryResource();

$resource->setType("public");

$resources = array();
$resources[] = $resource;

$activityAccess->setItems($resources);

$activity = new Google_Service_PlusDomains_Activity();
$activity->setObject($activityObject);
$activity->setAccess($activityAccess);

$plusdomains->activities->insert("me", $activity);
```

Comment: have the same problem. Have call to they support thay register my questions)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with:

```
$resource->setType("domain")
```

https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating